# Is there a way to call the useQuery from Convex recursively in next js 13?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

This is the Component I am working with.

I have a document(DocumentType), it has a property "parentDocument" which denotes the id of a parent document. It is like a tree structure.

I want to run the findRootParent() recursively but Next Js is giving me an error saying too many hook calls.

```
const documentType: { _id: Id<"documents">; _creationTime: number; parentDocument?: Id<"documents"> | undefined; content?: string | undefined; coverImage?: string | undefined; icon?: string | undefined; title: string; userId: string; isArchived: boolean; isPublished: boolean; }
```

```
import { api } from '@/convex/_generated/api'
import { Doc, Id } from '@/convex/_generated/dataModel'
import { useQuery } from 'convex/react'
import { Menu } from 'lucide-react'
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation'
import React from 'react'
import Title from './Title'

const Navbar = ({
  isCollapsed,
  onResetWidth,
}: {
  isCollapsed: boolean
  onResetWidth: () => void
}) => {
  const params = useParams()
  const { data } = useSession()
  const document = useQuery(api.documents.getById, {
    documentId: params.documentId as Id<'documents'>,
    userId: data?.user?.email || '',
  })

  function findRootParent(
    d: Doc<'documents'>,
    documentList: {
      id: Id<'documents'>
      title: string
    }[]
  ) {
    if (!d?.parentDocument) {
      return documentList
    }

    // Check if parentDocument is in the cache
    if (d.parentDocument) {
      const parentDocument = useQuery(api.documents.getById, {
        documentId: d._id as Id<'documents'>,
        userId: data?.user?.email || '',
      })

      return findRootParent(parentDocument as Doc<'documents'>, [
        ...documentList,
        {
          id: parentDocument?._id as Id<'documents'>,
          title: parentDocument?.title as string,
        },
      ])
    }

    return documentList
  }

  if (document === undefined) {
    return (
      <nav className='bg-background px-3 py-2 w-full flex items-center gap-2 text-muted-foreground pt-4'>
        <Title.Skeleton />
      </nav>
    )
  }

  if (document === null) {
    return null
  }

  const rootParentDocument = findRootParent(document, [])
  console.log(rootParentDocument)

  return (
    <>
      <div className='bg-background px-3 py-2 w-full flex items-center gap-2 text-muted-foreground'>
        {isCollapsed && (
          <Menu
            role='button'
            onClick={onResetWidth}
            className='h-6 w-6'
          />
        )}
        <div className='flex items-center justify-between w-full'>
          <Title initialData={document} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

I expect the function to return an array of elements which would lead to the parent item, Does anybody has any solution to this?